# access a value of a column of an n-uplet in django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I need help, please.

I've got an SQL database and my model name is: "Image" which has an integer model field "size"

I want to select the value of the size of the last image on my database, I tried this on SQL and it works:

```
select size from app_image where id = (select max(id) as maxenreg from app_image);
```

But when i use this on my view :

```
var = Image.objects.raw('select size from app_image where id = (select max(id) as maxenreg from app_image)')
```

it didn't give the same result.
Is there any query set of Django equivalent to that or any other solution to get this value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = Image.objects.values('size').order_by('-id')[:1]
size = i['size']
print(size)
```

try this

Comment: This will give the whole tuple, i need just the value of a field "size" of that last tuple

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it gives <Queryset [{'size': 500L}]> and me i just need the value 500 because i want to give it as an argument to a script bash on my django view